# Matching between a vector and multiple vectors in a list in R

Tags: r, match

I have a list of vectors such as:

```
>list

[[1]]

[1] "a" "m" "l" "s" "t" "o"

[[2]]

[1] "a" "y" "o" "t" "e"

[[3]]

[1] "n" "a" "s" "i" "d"
```

I want to find the matches between each of them and the remaining (i.e. between the 1st and the other 2, the 2nd and the other 2, and so on) and keep the couple with the highest number of matches. I could do it with a "for" loop and intersect by couples. For example

```
for (i in 2:3) { intersect(list[[1]],list[[i]]) }
```

and then save the output into a vector or some other structure. However, this seems so inefficient to me (given than rather than 3 I have thousands) and I am wondering if R has some built-in function to do that in a clever way.

So the question would be:

Is there a way to look for matches of one vector to a list of vectors without the explicit use of a "for" loop?

Comment: My first impulse was to search for an analogue for `outer()` that works on `list`s, then do something along `outer(foo,foo,function(x,y)length(intersect(x,y)))`, where `foo` is your `list`. However, you may not be able to beat a `for` loop that way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1722565/452096

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a built-in function for this. The best you could try is something like:

```
lsts <- lapply(1:5, function(x) sample(letters, 10)) # make some data (see below)
maxcomb <- which.max(apply(combs <- combn(length(lsts), 2), 2,
  function(ix) length(intersect(lsts[[ix[1]]], lsts[[ix[2]]]))))
lsts <- lsts[combs[, maxcomb]]
# [[1]]
#  [1] "m" "v" "x" "d" "a" "g" "r" "b" "s" "t"

# [[2]]
#  [1] "w" "v" "t" "i" "d" "p" "l" "e" "s" "x"
```

A dump of the original:

```
[[1]]
 [1] "z" "r" "j" "h" "e" "m" "w" "u" "q" "f"

[[2]]
 [1] "m" "v" "x" "d" "a" "g" "r" "b" "s" "t"

[[3]]
 [1] "w" "v" "t" "i" "d" "p" "l" "e" "s" "x"

[[4]]
 [1] "c" "o" "t" "j" "d" "g" "u" "k" "w" "h"

[[5]]
 [1] "f" "g" "q" "y" "d" "e" "n" "s" "w" "i"
```

Comment: Is a fantastic piece of code. I did not entirely express myself before. I want to keep the maximum number of matches for EVERY element of the list. For example, for the 1st element of the list (lsts) you created, the maximum matches occur between the 1st and second elements of the list. Now, I am trying to write a program that does the same for the second (i.e. compares the second with all and then finds a max match), for the 3rd and so on. Maybe sub-setting the matrix combs? Nevertheless, thank you, your code already gave me a lot to work with.

Comment: Yes, you basically want to do something similar and use symmetry of the combinations. Give it a try and let me know later today if you can't get it to work.

Comment: I used expand.grid and then subset for each element to focus juts on the combinations of this element with the remaining, excluding the element itself. It worked! ;) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
datal <- list (a=c(2,2,1,2),
           b=c(2,2,2,4,3),
           c=c(1,2,3,4))

# all possible combinations
combs <- combn(length(datal), 2)
# split into list
combs <- split(combs, rep(1:ncol(combs), each = nrow(combs)))

# calculate length of intersection for every combination
intersections_length <- sapply(combs, function(y) {
  length(intersect(datal[[y[1]]],datal[[y[2]]]))
  }
  )

# What lists have biggest intersection
combs[which(intersections_length == max(intersections_length))]
```