# Make multiple wilcox test using a function with r

Tags: r

I would like to generate 10 wilcoxon test (in the following exemple) using all the combination of groups present in my data.frame without writing them one by one. The idea would be to write a function that can also works with other data (in particular with data containing more groups) without modifying the code. The output would be a data.frame with all combinaisons of my groups in two variables and a third variable with the p value (not corrected for multiple test because I will correct it after) of the test.

Please see an data example:

```
data_test = data.frame(group=sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"), 200, replace = TRUE),
           value=sample(1:100, 200, replace=TRUE))

> data_test
    group value
1       C    39
2       E    36
3       E    45
4       E    47
5       D    89
6       B    72
7       E    57
8       A    67
9       A    78
10      C    87
11      D    99
12      D    94
13      C     2
14      A    24
15      A    84
16      D    69
17      E    82
18      E    96
19      E     5
20      B    33
.....
```

I could construct a data.frame with all the combined group in two variable as following

```
tab_stat=lapply(1:2, function(y) combn(unique(data_test$group), y))

tab_stat_2 = as.data.frame(t(tab_stat[[2]]))
colnames(tab_stat_2) = c("Group1", "Group2") 

> tab_stat_2
   Group1 Group2
1       C      E
2       C      D
3       C      B
4       C      A
5       E      D
6       E      B
7       E      A
8       D      B
9       D      A
10      B      A
```

But I don't know how to write the function. I will appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: There is already a function called `pairwise.wilcox.test` that does this.  You could look at the code to see how it works.

Comment: `combn` accepts a function `do.call('rbind', combn(unique(data_test$group), 2, simplify = FALSE, function(x) {d <- data_test[data_test$group %in% x, ]; data.frame(Group1 = x[1], Group2 = x[2], p.value = wilcox.test(value ~ group, d)$p.value)}))`

Answer (score 3):

You can get what you want with

```
pairwise.wilcox.test(data_test$value,data_test$group, p.adjust.method = "none") |> 
  broom::tidy()
```

But if you want to roll your own..here's a possible function using `expand.grid` to make the initial data frame, then `mapply` to get the p-values and `subset` to only select each pair of levels once.

```
do_pairwise_wilcox <- \(dat){
  expand.grid(Group1 = unique(dat$group),Group2 = unique(dat$group),stringsAsFactors=FALSE) |> 
  within(pval<-mapply(X=Group1 , Y=Group2 , \(X,Y) wilcox.test( dat$value[dat$group==X] , dat$value[dat$group==Y])$p.value)) |>
  subset(Group1<Group2)
}
```

output with a randomly generated dataset:

```
> do_pairwise_wilcox(data_test)
   Group1 Group2       pval
3       C      B 0.60113901
4       E      B 0.98947241
5       D      B 0.26180728
6       B      A 0.65923762
8       C      A 0.24423928
9       E      A 0.26228971
10      D      A 0.02047089
14      E      C 0.79866838
15      D      C 0.36693709
24      E      D 0.37433262
```

vs

```
> pairwise.wilcox.test(data_test$value,data_test$group, p.adjust.method = "none") |> 
    broom::tidy()
# A tibble: 10 × 3
   group1 group2 p.value
   <chr>  <chr>    <dbl>
 1 B      A       0.659 
 2 C      A       0.244 
 3 C      B       0.601 
 4 D      A       0.0205
 5 D      B       0.262 
 6 D      C       0.367 
 7 E      A       0.262 
 8 E      B       0.989 
 9 E      C       0.799 
10 E      D       0.374
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

first convert your data to list:

```
  data_test <- 
  data_test %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    summarise(value = list(value)) %>% 
    ungroup %>% 
    rowwise %>% 
    transmute(value = list(list(group = group, value = value))) %>% 
    pull
```

And then call an [outer()-like function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5544773/5043424):

```
  outerList <- function(a,b, fun) {
    outer(a, b, 
    function(x, y) vapply(seq_along(x), function(i) fun(x[[i]], y[[i]]), numeric(1)))
  }


  outerList(data_test, data_test, \(x, y) {
            wilcox.test(x$value, y$value)$p.value 
    })  %>% 
    data.frame %>% 
    `names<-`(lapply(data_test, \(x) x$group) %>% unlist) %>% 
    mutate(rnames = (lapply(data_test, \(x) x$group) %>% unlist)) %>% 
    pivot_longer(-rnames)
```

The result (for `set.seed(30)`):

```
# A tibble: 25 × 3
   rnames name  value
   <chr>  <chr> <dbl>
 1 A      A     1    
 2 A      B     0.537
 3 A      C     0.702
 4 A      D     0.559
 5 A      E     0.358
 6 B      A     0.537
 7 B      B     1    
 8 B      C     0.639
 9 B      D     0.205
10 B      E     0.110
# ℹ 15 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```